# regex: Searching for specific values in a specific location of a string

Tags: regex

Im fairly new to regex and im looking how to search for a specific value at a specific locaiton within a string.

i work closely with a telegram system and i am looking to search for a specific value within the standardized telegram.

for example:

locations: 01234567890123456789

telegram:  @.?55_**5**0-*8S7/**#8**H708

im looking for a regex expression that would return all strings with value 5 at location 6 and value #8 at locations 15/16.

thank you for all of your help!!!

Comment: I think it's easier to just get the character at that required position and check it programmatically.

Comment: '.....5.......#8' seems to work

Answer (score 0):

If in this string telegram: @.?55_**5**0-*8S7/**#8**H708 the 5 marked as bold is the 6th position, I think this would be a possibility:

[`^.{5}5.{7}#8.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/XcSjIH/1)

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Any character 5 times `.{5}`
- Match a `5`
- Any character 7 times `.{7}`
- Match `#8`
- Any character zero or more times till the end of the line `.*$`

If the `@` sign is part of it, you could use `^@.{5}5.{7}#8.*$`

If you would like to match `telegram: @.?55_50-*8S7/#8H708` you could do it like this:
[`telegram:\s@.{5}5.{7}#8.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/9W4oYU/1)